# if statement for if logical contains at least one TRUE (R)

Tags: r, if-statement, logical-operators

I am creating an if statement for whether an output contains a specific string or not. I am using regular expression to do so.

I am using the grepl() function to investigate if the output contains the string 'Final evaluation: none (in check)' within the variable 'stockfish_response'. This then contains a logical matrix of FALSEs and TRUEs. E.g:

FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE

```
grepl('Final evaluation: none \\(in check\\)', stockfish_response)
```

To incorporate this into an IF ELSE statement I need a logical process to check if a TRUE exists at least once in this matrix. Is there a function which will return TRUE if the logical matrix contains at least one TRUE and FALSE if the logical matrix contains no TRUEs.

For instance:

```
grepl_output <- grepl('Final evaluation: none \\(in check\\)', stockfish_response) 

if (grepl_output == TRUE){
  print('the phrase \'Final evaluation: none (in check) string \' exists')
} else {
  print('the phrase \'Final evaluation: none (in check) string \' does not exist')
}
```

whereby grepl_output == TRUE is not just constrained to the first logical in the list and returns TRUE if any value in the list is TRUE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you use any?

```
if any(grepl_output == TRUE) {
  # do something ...
}
```

See ?any for details.

Comment: `x == TRUE` is generally a long way to write `x`. (If `x` is `TRUE`, then you don't need `==` to convert `x` to `TRUE`: it's already `TRUE`.)